# Why is this type not a valid substitute for the type parameter?

Tags: java, generics

I'm experimenting with using generics to support a configurable structure of delegating objects (decorators, wrappers). I want to build a chain of delegators that implements a target interface as well as a generic delegator interface.

I have this outline:

```
class Test {
    static interface Delegator<T> {}

    static class DelegatorChain<T extends Delegator<T>> {}

    static interface Foo {}

    static class FooDelegator implements Delegator<Foo>, Foo {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DelegatorChain<FooDelegator> chain = new DelegatorChain<FooDelegator>();
    }
}
```

But, when trying to instantiate the `chain` variable,  compiler complains:

> Bound mismatch: The type Test.FooDelegator is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<T 
>        extends Test.Delegator<T>>` of the type `Test.DelegatorChain<T>`

I admit that generics is like [magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_laws#Others) to me, but I can somehow acknowledge that FooDelegator is not a Foo that *extends* Delegator<Foo>, it simply implements both interfaces.

Given that it's clear what I want to accomplish, is there anything I can do w.r.t. generics to fix it, or am I just better of forgetting about it?

Comment: Why does your DelegatorChain's generic type need to extend Delegator<T>? You're delegator class is providing the type information. required by the Delegator and the FooDelegator provides the delegator implementation.

Comment: It doesn't compile because `Foo` isn't a `Delegator`. http://www.nabeelalimemon.com/blog/2011/01/self-bound-generic-types/

Comment: Yeah The types don't match. The Generic type <T> in DelegatorChain is a "FooDelegator" but the generic type required in the Delegator is "Foo". You'll need the extra generic type parameter that i provided in my answer to make it work as you intend I believe. or just leave of the constraint.

Comment: My question to you, from a design standpoint, does the DelegatorChain need to know both which Delegator it contains AND the interface the delegator implements? The answer to that could impact which of the answers already submitted fit your needs better.

Comment: @ty1824, Still thinking ... yes, it does need to know both. In the end the whole structure should be able to act as a Foo.

Comment: If that is the case, you might want to try out the two-parameter solution by ScArcher2. `Type<T extends<C>, C>`. In that case, you are explicitly stating the interface (`C`), rather than implicitly (relying on the wildcard `?` in the `? super T` case). However, both solutions do match the specification, so it all depends on what you will need and how the data will flow once it's all created.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Under your definition, a Delegator is a Delegator of itself (like Comparable is for example), however it seems the intention is that Delegator is a Delegator of a super class. Luckily, generics has a way of expressing this:

```
static class DelegatorChain<T extends Delegator<? super T>> {}
```

This says that the "Delagator type must be a super class of T". With this change, the rest of your original code compiles:

```
static interface Delegator<T> {}
static class DelegatorChain<T extends Delegator<? super T>> {}
static interface Foo {}
static class FooDelegator implements Delegator<Foo>, Foo {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DelegatorChain<FooDelegator> chain = new DelegatorChain<FooDelegator>();
}
```

Also, anytime you use a generic super bound, your code looks really cool :)

Note: This following was originally the "first option" in the question.
There is another way to get your code to compile, but it is inferior because it loses the connect between the Delegator type and what it's delegating from:

```
// Not recommended, but will allow compile:
static class FooDelegator implements Delegator<FooDelegator>, Foo {} 
// However, this also compiles :(
static class FooDelegator implements Delegator<FooDelegator>, Bar {}
```

Comment: Agree, the second solution is cleaner, as long as you can grasp the super concept ;-)

Comment: +1 I am copying my comment from another post, as the second method DOES achieve what the asker specified. It specifies a chain of `Delegator`s that implement a target interface `?`: `Foo`, as well as a generic `Delegator` interface `T`: `Delegator<?>`. I believe the first method does this in an improper way, however.

Comment: Agreed - I only realised it after I posted. I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this is what you are trying to do.

```
static interface Delegator<T> {
    }

    static class DelegatorChain<T extends Delegator<C>, C> {
    }

    static interface Foo {
    }

    static class FooDelegator implements Delegator<Foo>, Foo {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DelegatorChain<FooDelegator, Foo> chain = new DelegatorChain<FooDelegator, Foo>();
    }
```

Your initial example does not compile because the types are not correct.
The Generic type  in DelegatorChain is a "FooDelegator" but the generic type required in the Delegator is "Foo". You'll need the extra generic type parameter that i provided in my answer to make it work as you intended.

You could also leave the constraint off entirely on DelegatorChain i.e. DelegatorChain.

Comment: It is not quite the same, rather, this is correct. It is only redundant because the C needs to be declared as a type when you use it within another Generic type declaration (T).

Comment: +1 I believe this achieves what the asker specified, it specifies a chain of Delegators that implement a target interface `C`: `Foo`, as well as a generic Delegator interface `T`: `Delegator<C>`.

Answer (score 0):

What should work instead is, if `FooDelegator implements Delegator<FooDelegator>` or `Foo implements Delegator<Foo>`. Because this is what you are requiring for the DelegatorChain: `T implements Delegator<T>`.

Third alternative, which should work as well:

```
DelegatorChain<T extends Delegator<F>, F> chain; ...
```