# bound mismatch error in java generic method when using self-referring type

Tags: java, generics

I am getting a bound mismatch error when using a self-referring type in a generic method, but not in a generic class declaration; here is an example of the faulty code:

```
public class Container {
   public static class User<X> {}  // line 1
   public static class Box<U extends User<Box<U>>> {} // line 2
   public static class NiceBox<U extends User<Box<U>>> {}   // line 3: OK
   <U extends User<Box<U>>> void niceMethod(U user) {}   // line 4: NOT OK
}
```

> Compile error message on line 4:  Bound mismatch: The type `U` is not a
>   valid substitute for the bounded parameter  `< U  extends
>   Container.User<Container.Box<U>>>` of the type `Container.Box<U>`

I don't understand why, thanks in advance for any help, 
SC

PS: Note that differently from previously asked questions, the problem presented here exists only with generic methods, the compiler accepts the problematic type bound when used within a generic class declaration.

I am using the compiler for Java 11 coming with the latest Eclipse distribution.

Here are more details on what I am trying to achieve.
I am building a Box that needs to execute some work on a target of type T within a context of type C, where this context C must satisfy a minimal interface.
Then I need to define methods to process a Box (hence the need for a generic method with the self-referring type bound).
Here is the code:

```
static class Box<T,C extends MinimalContext<Box<T,C>>> {
    void doSomething(T target, C context) {
        // do something
    }
}

interface MinimalContext<B> {   
    boolean validate(B box);
    void print(B box);
}

// FAILS:
<T,C extends MinimalContext<Box<T,C>>>
void processBox(Box<T,C> box) {}   

// Instead use:
class BoxProcessor<T,C extends MinimalContext<Box<T,C>>>    
{
    BoxProcessor(Box<T,C> box) {
        // use box as niceMethod would do 
    }
}
```

Note that since the limitation exists only for generic method and not for classes, I am using an inner class to do the work of the generic method...any other solutions?

Could someone from the eclipse developers say more about this limitation?

Comment: What's your Java version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this type not a valid substitute for the type parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032941/why-is-this-type-not-a-valid-substitute-for-the-type-parameter)

Comment: @fantaghirocco It doesn't seem like a duplicate of that question to me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is either a limitation of, or higher level of strictness from the Eclipse compiler. `javac` accepts that code fine.

In Eclipse you could write:

```
public static class User<T> {}
public static class Box<T extends User<Box<T>>> {}
<T extends User<Box<?>>> void niceMethod(T user) {}
```

You can then declare a class:

```
static class UserBox extends User<Box<?>> {}
```

And Eclipse will allow you to:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Container c = new Container();

    c.niceMethod(new UserBox());
}
```

But then it won't let you create a concrete `Box`. E.g:

```
Box<UserBox> b = new Box<>();
```

Is not allowed by Eclipse, but is by `javac`.

I suspect Eclipse might be doing the right thing, because you are saying:

"`Box` takes a type parameter of a class that extends a `User` with a type parameter of a Box which has a type parameter of the type we are extending." Which sounds impossible to me, but there could be something I'm missing.

EDIT (since the question was updated to show the interface):

Rather than define the interface as completely generic and try to restrict the context types in the definition of `Box` could you instead define a more restrictive interface, such as:

```
interface BoxContext<B extends Box<?, ?>> {
    boolean validate(B box);
    void print(B box);
}
```

You can then remove the self-referential generics from your definition of `Box`:

```
static class Box<T, C extends BoxContext<?>> {
    void doSomething(T target, C context) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Which then allows you to define your method:

```
<T, C extends BoxContext<?>> void processBox(Box<T, C> box) {}
```

Comment: I will describe the problem a bit more by editing my question. I will also say how I bypassed the limitation.

Comment: @stefanocasadei I have added another alternative solution.

Comment: I notice that in the `Box` class definition the type `C` extends `BoxContext<?>` rather than `BoxContext<B>`; just wondering, won't that reduce the usability of the variable `context`? For example the method `context.validate()` won't know that it's argument is of type `B`

Comment: No, because the interface has already defined that the validate method must take a Box, or a subclass of Box. Try it out!

Comment: Ok, I will try it out and then report back here

Comment: Unfortunately the interface BoxContext can not be restricted in my situation because it is also used with type parameters that do not extend Box